# Override toString in a Scala set

Tags: scala, tostring, scala-collections

I want to create a set of integers called `IntSet`. `IntSet` is identical to `Set[Int]` in every way except that its `toString` function prints the elements as comma-delimited (the same as if you called `mkString(",")`), and it has a constructor that takes a `Traversable` of integers. What is the simplest way to do this?

```
> IntSet((1 to 3)).toString
1,2,3
```

I'd think there would be some one-line way to do this, but I've been fiddling around with implicit functions and extending `HashSet` and I can't figure it out.

---

The trick is to use a proxy object. [Eastsun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172677/eastsun) has the answer below. Here's a slightly different version that defines a named `IntSet` type and makes it immutable.

```
import collection.immutable.{HashSet, SetProxy}

class IntSet(values: Traversable[Int]) extends SetProxy[Int] {
  override val self: Set[Int] = HashSet(values.toSeq:_*)
  override def toString() = mkString(",")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable

scala> def IntSet(c: Traversable[Int]): mutable.Set[Int] = new mutable.SetProxy[Int] {
     |   override val self: mutable.Set[Int] = mutable.HashSet(c.toSeq :_*)
     |   override def toString = mkString(",")
     | }
IntSet: (c: Traversable[Int])scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]

scala> IntSet(1 to 3)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = 1,2,3
```