# How do I specify a newBuilder for a scala set?

Tags: scala, builder, scala-collections

I am trying to extend a set of integers in Scala. Based on an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307213/override-tostring-in-a-scala-set) I have decided to use a SetProxy object. I am now trying to implement the `newBuilder` mechanism as described in chapter 25 of the second edition of *Programming in Scala* and am having trouble. Specifically I cannot figure out what parameter to specify to the `SetBuilder` object. Here is what I have tried.

```
package example

import scala.collection.immutable.{HashSet, SetProxy}
import scala.collection.mutable

case class CustomSet(override val self: Set[Int]) extends SetProxy[Int] {
  override def newBuilder[Int, CustomSet] = 
    new mutable.SetBuilder[Int, CustomSet](CustomSet())
}

object CustomSet {
  def apply(values: Int*): CustomSet = CustomSet(HashSet(values.toSeq: _*))
}
```

This does not compile. Here is the error.

```
scala: type mismatch;
 found   : example.CustomSet
 required: CustomSet
  override def newBuilder[Int, CustomSet] = new mutable.SetBuilder[Int, CustomSet](CustomSet())
                                                                                        ^
```

This is mystifying to me. I've tried various variations on the problematic value, but none of them work. How do I make this compile?

In addition to *Programming in Scala* I've looked through various StackOverflow posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416885/extend-scala-set-with-concrete-type), but remain mystified.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
case class CustomSet(override val self: Set[Int]) extends SetProxy[Int] {
  override def newBuilder = new mutable.SetBuilder[Int, Set[Int]](CustomSet())
}

object CustomSet {
  def apply(values: Int*): CustomSet = CustomSet(HashSet(values.toSeq: _*))
}
```

When creating the `SetBuilder`, specifying `CustomSet` as the second type param did not satisfy the type bound for that param.  Switching it to `Set[Int]` meets that criteria and allows you to still pass in your `CustomSet` as the constructor arg.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Proxy classes look like the ideal way to (effectively) subclass from traits with implementation classes that don't want to be subclassed. However, as of Scala 2.11.0, they have been [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312563).